# Starting Rails App with Phusion Passenger Standalone?

Tags: nginx, web-server, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, ruby

I am deploying a Rails application ( [Project Fedena](http://projectfedena.org) ) to a VPS at Digital Ocean.
I can use either of `mongrel_rails start` and `ruby script/server` to launch my app with no problem. It binds to port :3000 and I can use the application as desired.

The problem is with Phusion Passenger, I have installed the gem `gem install passenger` however, when I run `passenger start` from my rails app root, there's a permissions issue, which doesn't seem to be the case with Mongrel or Webrick:

```
=============== Phusion Passenger Standalone web server started ===============
PID file: /root/fedena/tmp/pids/passenger.80.pid
Log file: /root/fedena/log/passenger.80.log
Environment: production
Accessible via: http://0.0.0.0:3000/

You can stop Phusion Passenger Standalone by pressing Ctrl-C.
Problems? Check https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Standalone.html#troubleshooting
===============================================================================
2015/03/08 01:35:03 [error] 18827#0: *4 directory index of "/root/fedena/public/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.1", host: "0.0.0.0"
```

There is only one user (0) on this machine that owns all the directories. I've performed a recursive chmod on the directory to 777, 775, 755.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem turned out to be the passenger gem `passenger (5.0.2)` released just yesterday (March 7, 2015). This explains why I couldn't find anyone with my specific problem.

I solved this and successfully launched my rails application by uninstalling version **5.0.2** and installing version **4.0.59** (the last stable version from the 4.* branch):

1. `gem uninstall passenger -Iax`
2. `gem install --no-ri --no-rdoc --verbose passenger -v 4.0.59`

[Bug report](https://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=1108) filed. I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a `config.ru` file with following content to use passenger5 with rails 2.3 apps

```
# Require your environment file to bootstrap Rails
require ::File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/config/environment'

# Serve static assets from RAILS_ROOT/public directory
# use Rails::Rack::Static
# Dispatch the request
run ActionController::Dispatcher.new
```

Source : https://blog.phusion.nl/2015/03/04/phusion-passenger-5-0-1-released/